# A problem in using Dataframe :module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the following line of code:

```
Distance1= pd.Dataframe(columns=['Lat','Lon','PSC','SC_Avg_EcNo','SC_Avg_RSCP','MaxRSCP','MaxEcNo','count','PilotPollutionFlag'])
```

I got the error :

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'

I've seen similar questions like this and most of the answers were that either a file called 'pandas.py' is in the same directory as script, or that another variable called 'pd' is used in the program
but that doesn't happen in my program so what is the problem ?

Comment: The attribute is actually `pd.DataFrame`! that's all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typo, it should be `DataFrame`

```
                  ^
```

Note the letter 'F' has to be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

**import pandas as pd**

df1= {
'Country':['india','USA','RUSSIA'],
'population':[140,30,15]
}

df1 =pd.**DataFrame**(df1)

df2= {'Country':['india','USA','RUSSIA'],
'Capital':['Dlehi','London','Moscoe'] }

df1 =pd.**DataFrame**(df1)

df2=pd.**DataFrame**(df2)

pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on='Country')

Kindly take small example.
Dataframe should properly written in capital.